# How can I get a list of my most used programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I've decided to embrace pinning my most used programs onto the taskbar.

Obviously I can just trawl through the Start Menu and pick out the ones I think I use a lot, but is there any way that Windows can tell me what my most used programs are?

*(Ideally I'd like them ranked by number of times used, but I'm open to pretty much any criteria)*

Comment: Perhaps try this approach:  .....   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/programapp-history-and-usage/0df2e178-6212-49ac-a9bf-9aeee1d2b428

Comment: Number of times executable run? Number of minutes the executable has been running for?

Comment: @spikey_richie Either of those would be fine too. I'm open to pretty much any criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Windows already shows the most used apps in the Start menu.

To turn on this option:

- Run *Setting > Personalisation > Start*
- Turn on "Show the most used apps"
- It's useful to also have
  "Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar
  and in File Explorer Quick Access".

Comment: Not bad, but appears to be limited to only 6. Is there a way to see the rest of the list?

Comment: Seems like the number is hard-coded as 6.

Comment: Also, it is inaccurate. I have an app called "XBox Game Bar" in my most used list, and I have never in my life deliberately launched an app called that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many time tracking apps that could help you, for example free to use and open source [ActivityWatch](https://activitywatch.net/) that tracks time of active application windows.

Comment: Unfortunately the best time to have installed that would have been about a year ago!